# Getting stared with SleekXMPP

Tags: python, xmpp, startup

I am a newbie to XMPP World. I have being struggling getting my head around it. I found  a book called the Definitive Guide to XMPP. It uses the SleepXMPP library. There is a sample code I wanted to test, but didn't get through. I visited the SleekXMPP Getting Started guide, but still don't know how to get my head around it.

This is my problem. How do I run the code on this page [getting started SleekXMPP](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsleekxmpp.com%2Fgetting_started%2Fechobot.html%23the-final-product&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGN354qjnzCfIXzl5BBcvWJRz64Yw)

It says that:

> You can run the code using:
>
> python echobot.py -d -j echobot@example.com
>
> which will prompt for the password and then begin echoing messages. To test, open
> your regular IM client and start a chat with the echo bot. Messages you send to it should
> be mirrored back to you. Be careful if you are using the same JID for the echo bot that
> you also have logged in with another IM client. Messages could be routed to your IM client instead
> of the bot.

I have not created any password anywhere in the guide. I have not created any JID also. ANd what do they mean by a "To test, open
your regular IM client". Regular Client?

I am confused, any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think it means just that, "To test, open your regular IM client", Open Skype for an instance, or whatever client you use.

Comment: And then text who? The bot must be in my contact list